# Matrix inversion properties

Tags: matrices, inverse

I would like to know if there exist any identity regarding to the inverse of a matrix in which a row or (or a column) has been multiplied by a constant.

I know that if whole matrix is multiplied, inverse matrix is inverse of the original multiplied by the inverse of the constant.

Comment: If you are multiplying a row (or a column) by a constant then you will get a new matrix. And determinant and adjoint of a new matrix slightly different from that of the given matrix. So there is no such identity.

Comment: @AvinashN Well, there is: if the $i$-th column of the matrix is multiplied by $c\ne0$, then to get the inverse you just multiply the $i$-th row of the inverse by $c^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication of a column of matrix by a factor is the multiplication by a diagonal matrix.
For example if you want to multiply the first column of a matrix by $c\in \mathbb R$ you have to multiply from the right by the matrix 
$$
C:=\left(
\begin{array}
&c&0&\ldots &0\\
0&1&\ldots&0\\
0&0&\ddots&0\\
0&0&\ldots&1
\end{array}\right)
$$
now for any matrix $A$ we have 
$$(AC)^{-1}=C^{-1}A^{-1}.$$
Calculate $C^{-1}$ and you have a formula for the inverse of the product.